# Creating a child facebook app with existing facebook app using facebook API

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can we create facebook apps with existing facebook app and can set the urls of the newly generated apps?

little help, or a link about this in javascript or php would be a great help.

Comment: You can't dynamically create an application via another app, if I get the point of the question right.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create new apps via the API but can manage one once it's created - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/ for a list of the fields you can edit, and example API calls

Comment: Thank you. Now for example if i want to set the canvas_url of my a new app with an existing app then how will i do it? can you give me a little demo.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you'd have to unset the namespace from one app if you wanted to use it with a different one, but both apps could have the same callback URL (indicating that they use the same codebase)